# Forwarding MySQL Server ports

Tags: networking, mariadb

I’ve set up a Mariadb server on my raspberry pi and I can access it over 192.x.x.x but I can’t access it over my public IP address, I know I need to port forward can anyone tell me how to do this exactly, I use talk talk wifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a port forward as you mention.

```
external IP:port > Internal IP:port
x.x.x.x:3306     > 192.x.x.x:3306
```

The default port of MySql is 3306.

Comment: Forwarded the ports, but trying to connect on MySQL workbench and it doesn’t connect it just doesn’t work? Any ideas

Comment: yes, you must have a valid user/password and host. Try to check the account you are using to connect, you may have to use a wildcard on the host to allow all hosts.

Comment: So let’s say I have the account set up, would I use the external ip used in port forwarding in order to connect?

Comment: If a I am not wrong it would be the internal ip on the device doing the NAT, the router internal IP.